# Catching the white ball.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question.

There are $19$ black balls and 1 white balls (total $20$ balls) in the bin. You pick one ball each time without replacing. When is the maximal likelihood that you pick white ball?

I suspect it is on the middle (after $10$ times) but I can't prove.

Please explain in details.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Maximal likelihood" is almost certainly the wrong term to use here. Fortunately, your question is clear enough without the right words ...

Comment: There are three different interpretations to the question that it sounds like you might be asking.  The first interpretation: On average, how many draws are required to draw the white ball?  The second interpretation: What is the minimum number of draws you must perform to have at least a 50% chance of having drawn a white ball?  The third interpretation: Which specific draw (or draws) has the highest chance of the ball being white?  Each of these questions have different answers.

Comment: The answers to the questions in my previous comment are: 1) $10.5$, 2) $10$, 3) All draws are equally likely to be the draw to have the white ball.

Comment: @JMoravitz; I am asking for (1), i.e. on average how many draws are required to draw the white ball?

Comment: To see why the answer is $10.5$, begin by noting the third question and the answer that all draws are equally likely to be the white ball.  Then, remember the definition of the [expected value of a random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) and use the interpretation that it is the weighted average of the possible results.  As they are all weighted the same, this is simply the average.  We have then the final result of $\frac{1+2+3+\dots+20}{20}=\frac{21}{2}=10.5$

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz!

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Try computing the probability explicitly.

$P(X=1)= \frac{1}{20}$

$P(X=2)=\frac{19}{20}\frac{1}{19}$

Hopefully you can spot a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're asking the third of JMoravitz's questions (but the other two could be right as well).

The probability of not having picked W after $k>0$ picks is $\frac{19}{20} \cdot \frac{18}{19} \cdots \frac{20-k}{21-k} = \frac{20-k}{20}$.

The probability of then picking the white ball is $\frac{1}{20-k}$.

So the probability of picking the white ball on the $k+1$ pick is 
$\frac{1}{20-k} \cdot \frac{20-k}{20} = \frac{1}{20}$.

Comment: Given that the first pick was not the white ball, there remain $18$ black balls and one white ball out of $19$ balls total, it is no longer $20$ balls remaining.  The way you have written this as well is ambiguous without the use of $\cdots$ as it appears as though you are suggesting that each result has the product of exactly three fractions, only one of which depending on $k$.

Comment: Pure stupidity on my part and typing too fast when I had something on the stove beeping at me to deal with it...I'll fix.  Done (I think!)  (The missing "\cdots" came from my typing "\cdot". Sigh.)

Comment: @JMoravitz; I am asking for (1), i.e. on average how many draws are required to draw the white ball? – dice 1 min ago   edit